# R concatenate every few elements of a vektor

Tags: r, vector

I was wondering, if there is a way in R to concatenate elements of a vektor *without a loop*. For example concatenate every 3 elements like this:

Before:

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

After:

```
"1 2 3" "4 5 6" "7 8 9"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can split the string using a lookaround regex

```
trimws(strsplit(str1, '(?<=([^ ]\\s){3})', perl=TRUE)[[1]])
#[1] "1 2 3" "4 5 6" "7 8 9"
```

If we have a numeric vector, create a grouping variable for every 3 consecutive elements with `gl` and use one of the group by functions (`tapply`) to `paste` the elements together.

```
v1 <- 1:9
tapply(v1, as.numeric(gl(length(v1), 3, length(v1))), 
          FUN= paste, collapse=' ')
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It seems to work, when it is in a character form in quotes like "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", but my vector is in this form: `[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` without the qoutes. How do i get the quotes around the whole vector or how do I apply this directly on the vector?

Comment: @Borsi is you vector is just `1:9`? If so, you need to update your question. Or try `strsplit(paste(str1, collapse = " "), '(?<=([^ ]\\s){3})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]`

Comment: Yeah, my vector is just 1:9. My bad on formulating my question badly. But your first answer works for the question and your second answer works for the vector 1:9 perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, actually I still have a problem. I'm reading in binary data and the vector for example looks like this: `[1] 37 48 f0 de f7 40 99 3f 69`. Now I want to have for example a vector which elements contain each 3 bytes. Like this: `"37 48 f0" "de f7 40" "99 3f 69"`. `strsplit(paste(str1, collapse = " "), '(?<=([^ ]\\s){3})', perl=TRUE)[[1]]` doesn't seem to work on this, it doesn't split the string. So what do I have to change there?

Comment: @Borsi The second option works for me. `v2 <- c(37, 48, 'f0', 'de', 'f7', 40, 99, '3f', 69);tapply(v2, as.numeric(gl(length(v2), 3, length(v2))), FUN = paste, collapse=' ')#
#         1          2          3 
#"37 48 f0" "de f7 40" "99 3f 69"`

Answer (score 1):

is a hidden loop allowed?

```
apply(matrix(1:9, 3), 2, function(x) Reduce(paste, x)) # or
apply(matrix(1:9, 3), 2, Reduce, f=paste)
```

if not:

```
tapply(1:9, gl(3,3), function(x) Reduce(paste,x)) # or
tapply(1:9, gl(3,3), Reduce, f=paste)
```